# How to use Jquery validate for Id or Array name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have elements like this:

```
<input id="Title_name" type="text" name="Title[name]" maxlength="10" size="10">
<input id="Title_description" type="text" name="Title[description]" maxlength="100" size="60">


$("#title-form").validate({
        rules: {
            "#Title_name": "required",
            "#Title_description": "required",
        },
        messages: {
            "#Title_name": "Please specify your name",
            "#Title_description": "Please specify your name"
        }
    });
```

same like dropdown, radiobutton, checkbox etc and so on..

I want to use JQuery validate plugin for validation but its only works with "name" or with Array field name or ID and I want to use it with id or with array name.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you show what you tried in js code

Comment: @Deepanshu : I have edited my post. plz check it

Comment: so when you write one with # and the other without #, doesnot it work ?

Comment: @Deepanshu: I solved it by using array name like `Title[name]` now its working... btw thanks for help

Comment: ohk...thats what I was thinking what was the problem ...

Comment: @Deepanshu: Problem was previously I was passing like this Title['name'] instead of Title[name]

Comment: If you solved this, then please post your solution below as an answer.  Thanks.